# In MoonWalker, the film, what exactly was Michael implied to be?

Tags: moonwalker

At the end of the film *MoonWalker* Michael Jackson's fictional version is implied to be something more than human. He has a connection to falling stars which give him various transformative powers, including...

- A futuristic hyper-fast, sentient car
- A giant, silver-chromed, humanoid robot with force-fields and plasma blasters
- An interstellar ship capable of channeling his voice into light and sound energy blasts

It's never clearly **stated** however if he was an alien, a cyborg of some kind, or a human given morphing powers ala the *Power Rangers* or *Ultra Man.*

Are there any sources that speak to what he was?

Comment: He was a deep and weird look into Michael Jackson's subconscious.

Comment: @Buzz Ha! Funny! In that regard, he was just another avatar from one of MJ's videos. I can take that, but what about _in story?_ He has to be **some kind** of super being in order for the abilities and all to make sense, but even that fictionalized version seemed to imply Michael was a well known human with earthly ties. So where did the super powers come from?

Comment: There was a Movie Storybook and an official comic novelisation (Blackthorne 3D). I'm trying to acquire both as we speak in the hopes that either have some additional back-story

Comment: @Valorum Awesome. Keep me up on what you find. The Sega video games made it seem like he was an intergalactic warrior and protector of some sort, but that's all I have to go on.

Comment: What was Michael implied to be? A guy it's absolutely fine to let you kids hang out with :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"***Michael***" is a fictionalised version of the popular singer Michael Jackson. His connection with the stars, at least according to the film's [official storybook](https://archive.org/details/moonwalker-the-storybook/page/56/mode/2up), is that they possess ***magical powers*** that he can somehow access in times of extreme need.

**Car sequence:**

> "*Michael looks up at the beautiful night sky, as if he is looking for an answer in the stars. Perhaps he is - and perhaps there is magic in that sky*"

**Robot sequence:**

> *Michael, who often find magical strength from the stars in the night sky, looks up into the twinkling velvet sky, as if he's searching for a way to fight off the evil army he's facing.*

No further explanation is provided as to how or why he is able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other implication than he is a human.

At the end of the Moonwalker Movie cast is listed as<sup>[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhQntx6eghg)</sup>:

> **CAST**
>   Michael Jackson  as    Michael
>   Joe Pesci  as   Mr. Big
>   Sean Lennon  as     Sean
>   Kelley Parker  as   Katie
>   Brandon Adams  as   Zeke

Clip from [Youtube](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095655/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

On the Arcade game backstory is<sup>[3](https://www.mobygames.com/game/michael-jacksons-moonwalker)</sup>:

> Michael Jackson's Moonwalker is based on the Michael Jackson movie. Mr. Big has kidnapped children and has nasty things in store for them, like drugging them and making them slaves. So it's up to Michael to use his magical powers and dancing talent to try to catch Mr. Big and rescue his little friends.

[image: title screen]

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: A little plot irony here, perchance?